# Multiple level subdomain configuration in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns, subdomain

How can I have multi level sub domains in ruby on rails ?

Currently if I want to create a sub domain, I configure this is routes.rb.

```
constraints :subdomain => 'my' do
   mount API => '/'
    mount GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine => '/documentation'
end
```

This will create support for my.domain.com

However, if I wish to have another level api.my.domain.com, what can i do to have one more level of subdomain in the routes ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could nest your subdomain definitions. The subdomain constraints can be regular expressions so you could do something like

```
constraints subdomain: /.*my/ do
  constraints subdomain: 'api.my' do 
    mount API => '/'
    mount GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine => '/documentation'
  end

  # Non-API my subdomain routes
end
```